# Get document library selected item url in javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, document-library, modern-pages

I have a document library added as web-part to a modern page. Also have a JavaScript  added to the page, I want to fetch the item URL of clicked item in JavaScript.

Are there any ways to achieve this?

In classic I can generate the URL via DOM, but in modern I cannot find anything relevant in DOM.

`legacypagecontext.listID` or `ListURL` returns the ID/URL of SitePages library (where the modern page is added).

Comment: Are you trying to get this in SPFx? How are you adding the javascript in your page?

Comment: No not SPFx, via javascript. Javascript is added via SPFx application customizer to all pages

Comment: If you are using it on classic pages then try using `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()`.